# Undefined $event when trying to generate a path

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

To upload a picture into Firebase storage, I am creating a path for the **AngularFireStorage.upload** method:

In the template, an input to select the file:

`<input type="file" class="file-upload" (change)="genPath($event)" accept="*.png.jpg" id="">`

In the TS class, a method to generate the path:

```
path!:string;

  genPath(source:any){

    this.path = source.path.target;

  }
```

When I don't specify (any): I have the following error message

> Parameter 'source' implicitly has an 'any' type.

but when I do then call the upload method, the console has this answer:

```
uploadImage(){
    console.log(this.path);

    this.AngularFireStorage.upload("/files"+ Math.random()+ this.path,this.path)
    
  }
```

[console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNPG1.png)

Comment: First of all, add spaces around + on both sides to prevent unexpected behaviour. For example +"0" will try to cast a string to a number type. Second, try `console.log(source)` to see the output and check if you have the correct variables. I think you need `source.target.path` but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DFSFOT this was i recieve when i console.log(source):


FileList {0: File, length: 1}
0: File {name: 'comissar.png', lastModified: 1615379155000, lastModifiedDate: Wed Mar 10 2021 13:25:55 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 277552, …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: FileList

Comment: Also:

Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'change', target: input.file-upload, currentTarget: input.file-upload, eventPhase: 2, …}

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the firebase storage rule:

```
allow read, write: if false;
```

to

```
allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
```